# Cant access methods from another class

Tags: java, methods, static

Im calling `DataComparison()`

```
public class SteganographyGUI {

    ...

    DataComparison dataComp;
    dataComp = new DataComparison();

}

public int getLSB(){
    String x = fileChooser1.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
    x = x.substring(x.length() - 10, x.length() - 9);
    return Integer.parseInt(x);
}
```

when some criteria are met. My problem is that, when I try to access getLSB by using `gui.getLSB()`

```
public class DataComparison {

    public static SteganographyGUI gui;

    ...


    public DataComparison(){

        lsb = gui.getLSB(); 

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        gui = new SteganographyGUI();
        gui.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Error appears - `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException`

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you share the stack trace of the exception you're getting?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: My guess is something in that first line of getLSB is null, most likely the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to call getLSB() in your DataComparison class, but you don't give it the reference of your SteganographyGUI class. So change the following line:

```
 DataComparison dataComp;
 dataComp = new DataComparison();
```

to:

```
DataComparison dataComp;
dataComp = new DataComparison(this);
```

And change the constructor as well:

```
public DataComparison(SteganographyGUI guiRef){
    gui = guiRef;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing cyclic calls in your code. Try another class just for the main and call its methods in order:

```
class 1: `public class SteganographyGUI {...}`

class 2: `public class DataComparison {...}

class 3:

`public class XXXX {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        gui = new SteganographyGUI();
        gui.setVisible(true);
    }
}` 

I have helped :)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you try to initiate static "*gui*" variable

```
gui = new SteganographyGUI();
```

you execute **SteganographyGUI** class constructor which (probably) calls **DataComparison** class constructor

```
public DataComparison(){

    lsb = gui.getLSB(); 

}
```

which uses static "*gui*" variable which is not set yet. This is the reason you got "java.lang.NullPointerException".

Yes, I know "the exception message is misleading" :)